# Adding a css in preprocess view not woking

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I'm trying to add a css to a view, through the preprocess view as below

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
 $view = &$vars['view'];
if ($view->name == 'gallery_view') {
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/assets/js/responsive-image-gallery/gallery.js');
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/assets/css/responsive-image-gallery/style.css');
 }
}
```

The Following code above is inserting the js file but not the css. Is there a reason why? Or other way to insert css file in certain view?

I have tried the following and its being inserted:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'zenon') .'/assets/css/responsive-image-gallery/style.css');
```

So is there something missing in the drupal_add_css function or it doesnt have read access on the server, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trudog way below is a workaround for the css file to be inserted, and it works.

But after further debugging my case, I found the main cause of the problem was in the file permission. Apache did not have read access to the responsive-image-gallery folder. Resolved it with the following command on the server:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/Demo/sites/all/themes/mytheme/assets/css/responsive-image-gallerry
```

Then restarted apache just incase it did not take affect, and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

the path is wrong!

drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') already provides the path to your theme folder.  no need for '../../../...'

you should probably use

drupal_get_path('theme', 'zenon') . '/css/image-gallery/css/style.css'.

Comment: i tried your path, but it did not work. If the path was wrong, it would have given me a 404 in the console, but its not being inserted at all. Whereas the js is being inserted.

Comment: There's no reason why one would work and another not when they're one line apart - your path's are definitely wrong though, the return from drupal_get_path is the path to the theme, no need to traverse up and then back down again (plus you're missing a leading `/`). Make sure those are fixed first so you can rule out silly errors

Comment: Yes you're right about the paths, I have fixed them, but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Trudog, you should not use a relative path when using drupal_get_path.

Also, I'm surprised the javascript gets inserted because both paths are incorrect. The function drupal_get_path does not contain a trailing slash so what you get now is something like this (assuming your themes folder is in sites/all):

```
drupal_add_css('sites/all/themes/mytheme../../../themes/mytheme/assets/css/image-gallery/css/style.css');
```

The folder **mytheme..** probably does not exist. Adding a trailing slash would result in:

```
sites/all/themes/mytheme/../../../themes/mytheme/assets/css/image-gallery/css/style.css
```

Which is the same as:

```
sites/themes/mytheme/assets/css/image-gallery/css/style.css
```

That location probably does not exist either.

I think the correct call would be:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/assets/css/image-gallery/css/style.css');
```

The same goes for your javascript call.

Comment: I have already fixed the path as suggested by Trudog and you, please check updated post above. And even if path i wrong it would have given a 404 in console, but its not being inserted at all using drupal_add_css

Comment: Right, sorry, I was still composing my answer. Can you reach the CSS in the browser?

Comment: Its all right. Yes I can reach it through browser.

Comment: If you print drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/assets/css/responsive-image-gallery/style.css' to the screen and paste the result in your browser, does it still work?

Answer (score 1):

then try this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
 ... everything you already have there +
 $css_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/assets/css/responsive-image-gallery/style.css';
 var_dump($css_path);
 }
}
```

make sure that the string printed on the screen is a valid path to your css file by copying the printed string and putting it in browser's address bar + enter.  is should display the css content.  if 404, something's wrong with the path...  maybe spelling or something.